# Create Symlink in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, symlink

I want to create a symlink using a kubernetes deployment yaml. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: kubernetes deployment yaml creates kubernetes deployments, not any types of files anywhere, including symlinks...

Answer (score 1):

Not really but you could set your command to something like `[/bin/sh, -c, "ln -s whatever whatever && exec originalcommand"]`. Kubernetes isn't involved per se, but it would probably do the job. Normally that should be part of your image build process, not a deployment-time thing.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up adding the symlink in the entrypoint.sh and created a new image.